# Percentage change from category to category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I will like to create a new column that calculates the percentage change from JAN-FEB-MAR-APR-MAY-JUN which are in the COLUMN "MONTH" based on the COLUMN "TOTAL".
Here is a script I have tried but its not working

```
change perc = 
VAR ValueLastMONTH =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Sheet1[TOTAL] ),
        FILTER (
            Sheet1,
            Sheet1[MONTH]
                = ( EARLIER ( Sheet1[MONTH] ) - 1 )
                &&Sheet1 = EARLIER ( Sheet1[CATEGORY] )

        )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( ValueLastMONTH ),
        0,
        ( Sheet1[TOTAL] - ValueLastMONTH )
            / ValueLastMONTH
```

Here is the link to the power bi file. [enter link description here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjyBiUVuaNtJhTqaNqUPbm2h-cKl?e=Tuvp3K)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I will like a script in power bi that will calculate percentage increase or decrease from one month to the previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993083/i-will-like-a-script-in-power-bi-that-will-calculate-percentage-increase-or-decr)

Answer (score 0):

The Column 'Month' is not of type date. How would PowerBi know the text APR represents April? You need to make this column a date.

Now you need to change the script to work with DateDiff:

```
change perc = 
VAR ValueLastMONTH =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Sheet1[TOTAL] ),
        FILTER (
            Sheet1,
            DATEDIFF(Sheet1[MONTH], EARLIER ( Sheet1[MONTH] ),MONTH) = 1
                && Sheet1[CATEGORY] = EARLIER ( Sheet1[CATEGORY] )

        )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( ValueLastMONTH );
        0; 
        ( Sheet1[TOTAL] - ValueLastMONTH )
            / ValueLastMONTH)
```